# Hide and Unhide Many Gameobjects on Button Click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to develop an augmented reality application using `Vuforia` . I have to show specific `Gameobject` for an Image Target , say cube for `Image Target` 1 and Rectangle for `Image target` 2 , triangle for `target` 3 and so on for 10 targets. Both the targets will be tracked simultaneously . All i want to do is show cube first and when button is clicked it should hide the rectangle . and Again when button is clicked , it should show triangle hiding both cube and rectangle . All these with a single button and on multiple clicks .
All i know is things are to be changed at `Defaukttrackableeventhandler.cs` script .

Whats i'm doing right now is each scene has a image target and a button for each `scene` , so when button is clicked , load `next scene` .
I know this is not the right way to do . I'm new and i'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script that has a list property of game objects and the active object:

```
public activeIndex = 0;
public List<GameObject> gos = new List<GameObject>();
```

Assign and create a function that handles the click:

```
public void ButtonClickEvent(){
    go[activeIndex].SetActive(false);
    activeIndex ++;
    if(activeIndex >= gos.count){
        activeIndex = 0;
        go[activeIndex].SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Add the script to a gameobject such as "GameManager", tie the click event to the object function. Add your objects to the list property in the inspector. Disable all gameobjects that are shapes..

This is untested code, but should get you close. This would move through the array of object and deactivate the current and activate the next.

Comment: I get many errors while doing so . [Here](https://ibb.co/fWDUbe) is the screenshot.

Comment: Sam Sundar, you got many errors because you put  method ButtonClickEvent() outside class body.

Comment: Im very new to programming . I dont know how to change it correctly :(

Comment: Well, the first step is learning the basics. Go grab a Unity3D / C# tutorial off the net and follow it. There's hundreds of youtube videos that will teach you. That's the best thing you can do at the moment, After you do that, go sit in the Unity3D IRC chat channel and you will have a constant flow of info and help at your finger tips. Best of luck!